# How do you rank based on 2 columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We've got two columns of random data. The *lowest* numbers in Cat are most valuable, and *highest* numbers in Dog are most valuable.

```
Cat   Dog      Rank
32   $214.86    =
1    $102.16    
666  $86.01     
69   $364.23
```

What formula would rank these?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to weight a small Cat relative to a large Dog. Here are two ways. Hopefully this can get you started:

If the inverse of Cat is weighted equally with Dog (i.e., halving Cat is equivalent to doubling Dog), then get the rank of Dog divided by Cat. Enter this into `C2` and fill down:

```
=PERCENTRANK(INDEX($B$2:$B$5/$A$2:$A$5,),B2/A2)
```

You could also add the relative rank of Cat (smallest to largest) with the relative rank of Dog (largest to smallest) (i.e., having the lowest score for Cat is equivalent to having the highest price for Dog). Again enter into `C2` and fill down:

```
=PERCENTRANK(INDEX(PERCENTRANK($B$2:$B$5,$B$2:$B$5)-PERCENTRANK($A$2:$A$5,$A$2:$A$5),),PERCENTRANK($B$2:$B$5,B2)-PERCENTRANK($A$2:$A$5,A2))
```

Comment: I honestly found this less confusing than the question (but only slightly).

Comment: Very well put. Any answer is potentially valid depending on what other considerations the OP has. Maybe the OP will be able to run with one of my ideas.